# Restarting Application on FormClosed event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I have designed a form and on FormClosed event I am restarting the Application by `Application.Restart();`

Now question is

1. Is the application restarting on same thread or on a new thread?
2. How can I **Close** the application **when my application is already running**?

Comment: Why would you want to restart the application when it is closed, on the first place?

Comment: I am not making any project just want to know working process of events

Answer (score 1):

The restarted application is a new process, so it is also a completely new thread.

To close use; `Application.Exit()`

To Kill: `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`

EDIT - Added Kill!

Comment: It will never work as, it will call FormClosed event and application i s restarted there.

Comment: Then Kill it. But you will get yourself in a lot of hurt if you are dependent on Close / Closing events.

Answer (score 0):

The application is restarted on a new thread.

I would work with the [`FormClosing Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) and set the [`FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel = true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) when I want the application not to actually be closed, and let it go when it has to be closed.

```
public void frmMyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if ("frmMyForm has to be closed and the application closed")
        e.Cancel = true;
    // else the e.Cancel will never be changed, then the application is closed normally.
}
```

The **FormClosing Event** is called when you make a call to `frmMyForm.Close()`.

Hope I understood the question right.

Comment: Then `Close Method` will do it. If not, that is because I don't get your point, so could you explain it in details?

Answer (score 0):

The current application will be Closed/Shutdown, and a new process (with the same startup arguments) will be created.

1. So this will be in a new thread. A new process even.
2. The current application will be closed by calling restart. The new application has to take care of its own closing.

You can prevent the closing of the current application, by cancelling the close in a FormClosing event (from an open form). Even if you can cancelling the shutdown, the new appliction will be started, and you will end up by having two instances of your application active.

Answer (score 0):

@Javed i think the best choice will be start new instance of your application using [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) while closing and give your first instance to die in peace;)